# Haskell - Merge two lists of tuples by first component

Tags: list, haskell, merge, tuples

I have the following lists of tuples:

**List 1:**

```
[("key-1", Type1, Type2, Type3), ("key-2", Type1, Type2, Type3)]
```

**List 2:**

```
[("key-1", Type4), ("key-2", Type4)]
```

and I want to merge these tuples by its first component so that the following result is produced:

**Result List:**

```
[("key-1", Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4), ("key-2", Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4)]
```

In what way can I create the result list?

Comment: Is the data sorted this way, every time, so that you can zip them together, or are they in a random order so that you have to match them up? What happens if one list has more items than the other?

Comment: @FrancisKing data being sorted and having the same amount of keys does not guarantee that all keys are present, so zipping will not work in general case even if those conditions are met.

Comment: @FrancisKing Yes, the arrays are sorted every time and it's guaranteed that the arrays have the desired amount of items.

Answer (score 1):

In general case I would go with converting to maps approach:

```hs
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

merge :: Ord a => [(a,b,c,d)] -> [(a,e)] -> [(a,b,c,d,e)]
merge left right = let
    mleft   = Map.fromList $ map (\(k, a,b,c) -> (k, (a,b,c))) left
    mright  = Map.fromList right
    mergeL (a, b, c, d) acc = case Map.lookup a mright of
        Nothing -> acc -- can't merge
        Just e  -> (a, b, c, d, e) : acc
    in foldr mergeL [] left
```

Note this will get rid of keys that are not present in both lists. In case you need to preserve those you can generate entry with some default values for `Nothing` case, add similarly looking `mergeR` and concatenate two `foldr` in result.